# Complex Fourier series for $f(x)=\cos(3x)$

Tags: fourier-series

I want to find $c_n$ satisfying

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_ne^{inx}=\cos(3x)$$

Noting that $\langle e^{inx},e^{-imx}\rangle=0$ for $n\neq m$ in $[0,2\pi]$, I have

$$c_m\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(m-m)x}\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(3x)e^{-imx}\,dx$$

but the RHS evaluates to

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(3x)e^{-imx}\,dx=\frac{i(1-e^{-2i\pi m})}{9-m^2}$$

with $e^{-2i\pi m}=1$ since $m\in\mathbb Z$. Thus $c_m=0$, which doesn't seem right. What am I missing?

Comment: By Euler's formula, $c_3=c_{-3}=1/2$ and all other $c_m$ are zero. No integration is required.

Comment: But if I put $3$ in to the RHS of my derived equation, $c_3$ diverges. I'm not sure why this would be?

Comment: It doesn't actually diverge: you get $0/0$ which is indeterminate.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I see my mistake. Thanks for your help!